# Guaranteed and ordered delivery in event bus of Vert.x?

Tags: vert.x

Does event bus of Vert.x support guaranteed and ordered delivery? If not, would using a MQ service to retain messages be the best choice to achieve that?

BTW I understand Vert.x has the pinciple of best-effort delivery.

Comment: Probably this is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768242/questions-for-vert-x-event-bus?rq=2